# Pass fluentd kubernetes logs to already running elasticsearch and kibana on physical server

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kubernetes, kibana, fluentd

My elasticsearch and kibana is already setup on physical server.
kibana Dashboard: **https://elkquest/app/kibana**
I am trying to pass k8s logs via fluentd to ES. I couldn't get any solution as all docs suggest to deploy ES cluster on K8S. How can I do it?

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-elasticsearch-fluentd-and-kibana-efk-logging-stack-on-kubernetes

Comment: Did you setup the fluentd in kubernetes? you need to configure your elasticsearch url in the fluentd yaml. See [here](https://docs.fluentd.org/container-deployment/kubernetes). If you already tried, please post the errors logs.